# Kibana Dashboard says could not locate that index-pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I am using `ELK - 7.10.1` Version.

Through `log-stash` initially i have uploaded `18-Jan-2021 and 19-Jan-2021 csv data` to `Elasticsearch` further i have visualized and created dashboard in `Kibana`. Again today i have did the below.

1. Deleted the index pattern`data-1` and deleted from `Saved Objects` sections as well.
2. I have uploaded my csv file data from `01-Jan-2021 to 19-Jan-2020`.
3. Again i have created new index pattern with the same name`data-1` earlier i had.
4. In `Discover` page i can view data from `01-Jan-2021 to 19-Jan-2020`.
5. In `Discover` page if i change the date for example: from `05-Jan-2021 to 15-Jan-2021`it says `No results match your search criteria`

Since i have data from -`01-Jan-2021 to 19-Jan-2021` in `Elasticsearch` but in Kibana if i change date something in between `date/time` frame it is not showing the data. I am not sure what is causing this problem, Ideally it should show data for available time range correct?

6. Also when tried to view my Dashboard it says below error message.

[image]

Can someone here help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Dashboard Could not locate that `index-pattern issue` and `Dashboard time-frame` issue resolved by below steps.

1. In problem visualized section replaced the `id` with `new index pattern id` and `saved` it that's all. Now able to view my dashboard.
2. Even `data in between time range view` issue also resolved by changing `Time field: '@timestamp' to Time field: 'date'` as per my csv file in `index-pattern` creation section, now on dashboard able to view the data between time frame. Now everything works as expected

Comment: The useful bit for me was that the index pattern ID is not the same as the index pattern name in v7. The ID is the UUID looking code that can be obtained from the URL.